# GeoIP Redirect EU USA UK

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, geoip

I was wondering if you could give me a code which works so when someone loads the site from the United Kingdom it redirects the user to /UK/ then if they load it from the US it goes to /US/ and if they're from anywhere in the EU excluding the UK to /EU/

I've tried this code and it's just saying 123.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>removed</title>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){

    if(navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
    }
    else
    {
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }

    function showError(error)
      {
      switch(error.code)
        {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
          alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
          break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
          alert("Location information is unavailable.");
          break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
          alert("The request to get user location timed out.");
          break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
          alert("An unknown error occurred.");
          break;
        }
      }

 function showPosition(pos)
  {

   if (pos.coords.longitude >= 45.775534 && pos.coords.longitude <= 45.775562 && pos.coords.latitude <= 15.994809 && pos.coords.latitude >= 15.994792)
        {
            alert("987");
        //window.location = 'USD/';
        }
        else{
            alert("123");
           // window.location = 'GBP/';
        }
  }
}//]]>  

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically redirection like this is performed on server-side by querying against the geolocation database. The JavaScript approach might work on the modern browsers and if user allows the page to query for the location.

Anyway, look carefully on the constraints for the latitude and longitude. As I see, it should be in the very tiny box lon 45.775534-45.775562 lat 15.994809-15.994792. This is a small square in Zagreb, Croatia. So unless your device use very precise geolocation and you actually in this location, it is hardly unlikely that you ever have 987 popup. If you want to check whether the user is in the USA, you should use much more complex matching (taking into account Alaska and Hawaii).